# SNS push notification service only success on dedicated device

Tags: push-notification, amazon-sns

I've been trying to use AWS SNS service to send notifications to Apple Sandbox environment . I think I setup everything ok and my dev iPhone can get notification without trouble.

But when I start to send notifications to others who install the test app , I keep seeing error message state that

> Platform token associated with the endpoint is not valid

With a messageId :147975e0-8a09-5223-8537-256320ab3733

From what I understand , if one device can success, others can success too.

Could anyone tell me how to debug this probelm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the apps that the other people are installing were not built with a dev cert (probably built with an adhoc or production provisioning profile), so you probably should use the production certificate.

You could try adding another application on SNS using the production certificate (or the same one, but not using Sandbox, depending on how you generated it), if it works, that this is it.

Also make sure you are using the correct bundle id associated with the certificate.

Comment: thanks, but I believe me and my colleagues are using the same version, and I ask AWS SNS, they say that it's the token other colleague provide is invalid so SNS reject the notification. I am contacting Apple to see what is going wrong.